# Adding Scroll to Div Function With UI Auto Complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/kPLew/151/)  and let me know how I can enable scroll to div of selected item from auto complete?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('change', function () {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + this.value);
        $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#"+ this.value).offset().top
         });
    }).change();
    $('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
    });
});
```

but I am getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `change` event does not exist so your code is not being triggered. you have to do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tags').on('autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
        $('#tagsname').html('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
        $('html,body').animate({
               scrollTop: $("#"+ this.value).offset().top
         });
    });
});
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrs4h950/).

Comment: What do you mean `change` doesn't exist? OP applied it to a text box not a select. If it didn't exist, it wouldn't fire and therefore the OP wouldn't be getting the error.

Comment: The JavaScript compiler check all your code before execution allocating your variables and it can check if a variable or a variable property exist before execution. On the other hand, the `change` event must be initialized to be able to be triggered, that's why you have to add it a callback on the `autocomplete` initialization. That's an observable pattern. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Comment: No, the event fires because the OP calls it. `.change();`

Answer (score 0):

The code works when it is properly triggered. But it is only properly triggered when you enter a value matching an id for one of the lookup items.

According to the [Jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for ID selectors:

> For id selectors, jQuery uses the JavaScript function
>   document.getElementById(), which is extremely efficient.

And as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for document.getElementById parameters

- element is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.
- id is a **case-sensitive** string representing the unique ID of the element being sought.

Since your elements are defined with ids using `Proper Cased` strings, and since id lookup is case sensitive, if you enter `asp` for the Asp element it will return `null` for the lookup.

Subsequently calling `offset()` on `null` will return `undefined`. Since `undefined` has no property `top` you get your error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

So the solution is to set your ids to some case and normalize your call. For instance if you used lower case then:

```
$("#"+ this.value.toLower()).offset().top
```

Or better yet do some null checks etc to ensure you actually have an item bfore you start calling methods on it:

```
function getOffset(id){
   if (this.value)
   {
      var matches = $("#"+ this.value.toLower());
      if (matches.length){
         return matches.offset().top;
      }
   }
   return 0;
}

scrollTop: getOffset(this.value);
```